# Как получить значение scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

routes.rb:

```
resources :pages

scope '/admin' do
  resources :pages
end
```

Мы получаем два пути `site.com/pages` и `site.com/admin/pages` которые ведут в один контроллер `pages_controller.rb`. Как в этом контроллере опознать что введен именно `site.com/admin/pages`. Где хранится значение scope? Парсить строку пути на наличие `admin` я думаю не лучшее решение?

Смысл в том чтобы отдавать разные вьюхи в зависимости от урла. Возможно есть лучший способ? Может лучше создать 2 контроллера `pages_controller` и `admin_pages_controller`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найти... можно, но лучше **просигналить явно** в параметрах. Я провёл вот такой эксперимент:

```
resources :pages, only: :index

scope '/admin', defaults: { admin: true } do
  resources :pages, only: :index
end
```

Если совпадёт маршрут внутри скоупа, `params[:admin]` будет `true`, а если нет, то его вообще не будет (т. е. попытка его получить вернёт `nil`).

**Почему?** Потому что система маршрутов, по сути, выполняет роль *преобразователя маршрута в параметры*. Если "админность" маршрута это параметр, обозначьте его явно.

Но сделать **отдельный контроллер** это [**хорошая идея**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30015974/2076787): можно будет сделать массу действий *на весь контроллер*: контроль доступа, предзагрузка нужных для админки данных... в конце концов, **у вас два разных набора вьюх!** *Уже это* явно напрашивается на отдельный контроллер. Общие их части можно вынести в модуль.

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно!